# How to draw an image in Python

Tags: python, image, drawing, python-imaging-library

I'm using PIL to load images and use them as textures on 3d meshes, but now I want to draw an image in the overlay. However, it doesn't work:

```
shared.back_dialogue = Image.openimage('DATA/Textures/Menu/back_dialogue.jpg')
ImageDraw.Draw(shared.back_dialogue)
```

I can't figure out how to define the position the image must be drawed to and apart from that PIL draws nothing at all. What do I do wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to use PIL to take the image and draw it on the monitor? The ImageDraw library is for drawing shapes on the image in memory - nothing is actually displayed. Try [`yourImageObject.show()`](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.Image.show) instead. And if you want to draw the image on the screen with no window box surrounding it or anything, I think that's beyond the power of PIL - you'll probably need some low-level OS interfacing APIs to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The function show() did nothing but opening mspaint every step. I want to show, as you see in almost every 3d game, an image on the HUD not in a window box but just on screen. Do you know a library to accomplish that?